# Duplicate custom fields "media" to make "image" plugin

Tags: joomla-4.x, custom-field

I am using the custom fields for the articles. I have downloaded the "media" custom field plugin and renamed this to "image" (along with the relevant files) I have installed the plugin, but it's not showing in the available fields in articles custom fields.

Ideally I want to show only the file upload for the media custom field and not browse the server, just upload the file and this is then selected.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure duplicating the media plugin is going to get you anywhere because even if you copy and rename the plugin to image, the layout that will be used will be the same, which will lead you back to the media manager.
So I think you would better off overriding the file in layouts/joomla/form/field/media.php
You can found more information about [overriding layouts here](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Layout_Overrides_in_Joomla#JLayout_Micro-Layout_Overrides).

Once you have your layout override you can modify the layout removing the code that accesses the media server and add some code to allow an image to be uploaded like in this example.

[image]